# The mobile phone set is almost the same AS mine Or LIKE mine?

Tags: difference, as-like

Which alternative is correct?

a) The mobile phone set is almost the same as mine.

b) The mobile phone set is almost the same like mine.

Comment: Of course there are sentences with "like" that also are correct, such as "The phone is much like mine", but you do want to use FumbleFingers' one.

Answer (score 3):

"The same as" is a fixed expression. Learn and remember that it is always "the same as", and that "the same like" simply does not exist, and you will be fine.

The Corpus of Contemporary American English has 6614 cites for "the same as", but only 2 for "the same like". The British National Corpus has 2548 and 0 cites, respectively.

Comment: Perhaps adding a comma, like *"The mobile phone set is almost the same, like mine,"* can evade the problem.

Comment: @Damkerng: Not really - unless *the same* refers to *something else* that both phones are similar to.